# Is there anything wrong with generating large migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I just sat down and figured out all the indexes I want in my program.  I already have 7 models in place and I realized I want to add 14 indices to the database.

This is my first real Rails project and the migrations I've made and seen in guides have been specific to just one model.  I haven't seen any guides explicitly comment on this one way or the other--is it considered a best practice to make one migration per model?  Or to limit the size and complexity of a migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration size doesn't matter. When your development is all done, you will be using

```
rake:db:schema:dump
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:load
```

It'll put everything into a concise file which will be used to recreate your production database.

Comment: Thanks for the big picture view!

Answer (score 1):

Generally I make my migrations purpose-driven. Its okay if they are big, but most of the time you want them small. Think of them like functions - easier to understand when small. Smaller migrations also make it easier to fix a problem if something goes wrong during the migration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  That's the tradeoff I was considering.  My migrations folder is getting a little long with these small patchwork migrations I've used to add a column here and there, so I think I'll just try making one large one first.  I can roll that back and break it up if I have problems with rake db:migrate

Answer (score 1):

This might be a minor point for most, and a big deal for some.

I was just cleaning house on a project.  I had a model that was unused.  I happily executed:

```
rails destroy scaffold LouseyModel
```

... and the scaffolding was removed.  This also removed the original migration file.  I suppose if you are one who keeps one action == one migration file, then this is no problem and a nice way to clean-up your development mess.  If you are one who likes to hand edit your migrations and add multiple things to a single migration file, then this might have the potential to introduce undesired behavior with db:setup and some other db rake tasks that depend on sequential migrations to do their thing.

Comment: This is a valid point, and is a side effect to be aware about.  At this point in my Rails development, I've learned to use Git pretty religiously.  Granted, recovering said migration would leave you with one that still had the LouseyModel name in it, but that's a very minor issue.  It's probably for reasons such as yours that it's recommended people use `rake db:schema:load` to load databases onto production machines.

Comment: Yes & Yes.  If I hadn't been introduced to git, I don't think I'd ever have gotten very far with Rails.